# How to convert/cast a jobject into jbyte*

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I would like to deal with a byte array which is retrieved from java callback function.
However, I got an error `'JNIEnv' has no member named 'GetObjectElements'`

```
jmethodID FuncGetArray = GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "GetArray", "()[B");
jobject data_obj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, FuncGetArray);
const jboolean is_copy = JNI_FALSE;
jbyte *byte_array = env->GetObjectElements(data_obj, is_copy);
```

Can I get the pointer to get the byte array in a easy way instead of retrieving each element and copying it.

Comment: Can you please add the signature of the java method you are calling? Are you expecting `Object[]` or a `byte[]`?

Comment: The signature of GetArray is "()[B".
I expect byte[] while there is not such method named GetByteArrayElements() of data_obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is `GetByteArrayElements`. You can cast the `data_obj` you have to a `jbyteArray` and pass it to that function.

Also you should be passing a pointer to `is_copy`.

Comment: `is_copy` is an optional output. It's simplest to pass a null pointer.

Comment: Oh. I got your point.  I should cast the `data_obj` to `jbyteArray`.
Besides, many thanks for your correction about passing a pointer to `is_copy`.